# Problem for install gazebo_ros_package

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I want to creat a plugin in gazebo, so i need the gazebo_ros_package.**
I use **linux 14.04 and ROS Indigo and gazebo 6.**
I try to install the **gazebo_ros_package**;

*$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control*

But it reponse that I need gazebo2 ,ros-indigo-gazebo-ros,ros-indigo-gazebo-ros and so on

then I use

*$ sudo git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git*

It works but when I use

*rosrun gazebo_ro gazebo*

It give me something like this

*/opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gazebo: 25: .: Can't open /share/gazebo//setup.sh*

where is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215796/problem-for-install-gazebo_ros_package/) by [huang0171](https://answers.ros.org/users/23561/huang0171/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is in the scripts located in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros.  There are several scripts (i.e. gzclient, gzserver, etc.) which are executed when you perform a rosrun command.  When trying to run gazebo, ROS needs to source the gazebo setup.sh script to make sure that the proper gazebo paths are defined.  This is the line in the ROS scripts which has a problem:

```
setup_path=$(pkg-config --variable=prefix gazebo)/share/gazebo/
```

The problem is that pkg-config should find the path to gazebo, but it doesn't seem to work.  Since it doesn't find gazebo, the script just continues execution using "/share/gazebo/" as the path.  I tried looking around, but couldn't find an easy fix.  Also, it looks like there is an extra slash at the end.

If you want a quick fix to just get things running, manually edit the gzserver and gzclient files to point to the directory which contains the setup.sh file.  The default install location is /usr/share, so I changed my scripts to this:

```
setup_path=/usr/share/gazebo
```

If anyone knows what the correct fix is, feel free to chime in.

---

Originally posted by [agoins](https://answers.ros.org/users/20362/agoins/) with karma: 81 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2015-08-26**:
Had the same issue (14.04 + Jade + Gazebo 5), solved by creating a file opt/ros/jade/lib/pkgconfig/gazebo.pc with the content

"prefix=/usr
Name: gazebo
Description: Description of gazebo
Version: 1.0.0
"

**Comment by [SAGAR SHENOY](https://answers.ros.org/users/62005/sagar-shenoy/) on 2020-10-30**:
Thanks a ton dude. I was finding a solution from many days .

**Comment by [Longshot](https://answers.ros.org/users/79288/longshot/) on 2021-08-02**:
You may need to execute following code after creating the workspace

```
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```